# Highlighting between two columns set as variables

Tags: vba

1) I  am trying to find the word "QTR" then set this activecell.column into a variable...
2) Then I do a CTRL +right 
3) then set this activecell.column into a variable. I need to select all columns between these two columns (inclusive)

```
 Sub Column()

    Dim cs As Range 'column start
    Dim cst As Range ' column end

    'Find 'QTR'

    Cells.Find(What:="QTR", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Set cs = ActiveCell.EntireColumn

    'CTRL + Right Arrow
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select

    Set cst = ActiveCell.EntireColumn

'highlight all columns from cs column to cst column
    Range(cs & cst).Select



    End Sub
```

It is causing n error. Please could someone help

Answer (score 0):

worked it out

```
Sub Column()

Dim cs As Integer 'column start
Dim cst As Integer ' column end

'Find 'QTR'

Cells.Find(What:="QTR", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

cs = ActiveCell.Column

'CTRL + Right Arrow
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select

cst = ActiveCell.Column


Range(Cells.Columns(cs), Cells.Columns(cst)).Select




End Sub
```